# R: getting the command line from the object

Tags: r, vector, command

On R, I have a vector, called X, which looks like:

> [1] "ind 30 FLG056_blue"       "ind 32 PJK056_blue"       "NTC PJK056_blue"           "ind 3 PJK056_red"
>    [5] "NTC PJK056_red"        "ind 1 PJK058_plate1bis"  "ind 9 PJK058_plate1bis"  "ind 17 PJK058_plate1bis"
>    [9] "ind 25 PJK058_plate1bis" "ind 2 PJK058_plate1bis"  "ind 10 PJK058_plate1bis" "ind 3 PJK058_plate1bis" 
>   [13] "ind 11 PJK058_plate1bis" "ind 4 PJK058_plate1bis"  "ind 12 PJK058_plate1bis" "ind 5 PJK058_plate1bis" 
>   [17] "ind 6 PJK058_plate1bis"  "ind 7 PJK058_plate1bis"  "ind 8 PJK058_plate1bis"  "NTC PJK058_plate1bis"
>   [21] "ind 1 PJK058_plate2"     "ind 2 PJK058_plate2"     "ind 3 PJK058_plate2"     "ind 27 PJK058_plate2"
>   [25] "ind 4 PJK058_plate2"     "ind 5 PJK058_plate2"     "ind 6 PJK058_plate2"     "ind 7 PJK058_plate2"
>   [29] "ind 8 PJK058_plate2"     "NTC PJK058_plate2"

I would like to know if there is a function, which would print the command to get this vector, like:

> "c("ind 30 FLG056_blue","ind 32 PJK056_blue","NTC PJK056_blue", [ETC])"

In order simple copy-paste the command to keep this vector

Thank you very much

Comment: Probably just `dput(X)`

Comment: That's it! Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

`dput(X)` should do the trick.

`dput()` outputs the text representation of an R object, in a form that can be read back into R.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
 xs <- unlist(strsplit(x[1], "\" \""))
```

This you will have a array like:
[1] "ind 30 FLG056_blue
[2] ind 32 PJK056_blue
[3] NTC PJK056_blue
[4] ind 3 PJK056_red"
Then you need fix the substrings...